# Add Angular Material to Lib in Nx Monorepo

Tags: angular-material, storybook

I am trying to view a story of an Angular Material Button. However, in the story, the button does not have any styles. I imported angular material using : `ng add angular/material` and these ara my files for my component :

This is the html file :

```
<button mat-button color="primary">Button Material</button>
```

This is the module of my lib :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { ElementComponent } from './element/element.component';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { MaterialComponent } from './material/material.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


export const plateRoutes: Route[] = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule,BrowserAnimationsModule, MatButtonModule],
  declarations: [
    ElementComponent,
    MaterialComponent,

  ],
})
export class PlateModule {}
```

This is the component story :

[image]

As you can see the style does not apply to the mat button...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your MaterialComponent you have to import the material module of Button

```js
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { Meta, moduleMetadata, Story } from '@storybook/angular';

import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component';

export default {
  title: 'button',
  component: ButtonComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [MatButtonModule],
    }),
  ],
} as Meta<ButtonComponent>;
```

And after this you will need to add the style in the storybook and build-storybook steps of the storybook

```json
{
...
"storybook": {
   ...
   "options": {
     "styles": [
       // the style that you should import
       "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
     ]
   },
 "build-storybook": {
   ...
   "options": {
     "styles": [
       // the style that you should import
       "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
     ]
   },
 }
...
}
```